# how can i reinstall magento2 libraries

Tags: magento2, installation

i tried replacing my vendor folder to check for a error. but i'm getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceInterface in
>   /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73

can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can replace vendor directory with the new one.**

**By the way Its Factory method error , you can resolved this by following below steps.**

1. Remove **var/generation , var/cache , var/page_cache** directory
2. run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command
3. run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** command
4. run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command
5. run **php bin/magento cache:clean** and **php bin/magento cache:flush** command

Comment: Happy To help keep helping :)